# Moving data into blank cell from the cell on its right

Tags: vba, excel

I have a matrix of data which contains 16 columns and 300 rows. This data I get it from FORTRAN code. So times I get some blank cells in first column and then that row would have 17 columns. Now I would like to shift the data into blank cells making the matrix uniform.

I am not an expert into VBA. It would be great if you help me with the problem.

So far I have

```
Sub fillBlanks(Optional ByRef currentSheet As Worksheet) 
  Dim blanx As Range 
  If currentSheet Is Nothing Then Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet 
  currentSheet.Activate 
  On Error Resume Next   
  Set blanx = Range("B1", currentSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address).SpecialCells(xl‌​CellTypeBlanks) 
  If blanx Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 
  On Error Goto 0 
  currentSheet.Range(blanx.Address).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]" 
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with this:

[image]

Running this:

```
Sub dural()
    For i = 1 To 15
        With Cells(i, 1)
            If .Value = "" Then .Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce this:

[image]